# Mixpanel People Analytics User Profile Avatar

Tags: facebook-graph-api, mixpanel

I've searched trough the API documentation but I cant find a property to set the User Profile avatar/thumbnail when using People Analytics. Is it possible?

I am using Facebook Graph API to get it and i wanted to save it to the user profile in mixpanel. But I am missing the "avatar".

```
  FB.api("/me/picture",function (response) {
    console.log('Avatar URL: ' + response.data.url);
    mixpanel.people.set({
      "avatar": response.data.url
    });
  });
```

Cheers

EDIT:
Well, I've contacted Mixpanel support and they answered me the following:

"*Currently, Mixpanel automatically pulls in users' profile pictures if the user's email is associated with a [Gravatar](http://gravatar.com) global avatar account. There isn't a way to manually control this for the time being, so any users who don't have Gravatar profiles will unfortunately not have profile pictures.*"

That means, it is not possible to do it as we speak. I contacted them a little further and apparently, they already have that feature in mind for the near future.

Comment: Thanks for your EDIT. I'm waiting for this picture as well as I have a nice picture URL sitting in my database waiting to be pushed to Intercom/Mixpanel :)

Comment: see answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72071555/710284
Probably a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Mixpanel automatically pulls user's avatars from this website: https://en.gravatar.com/

If a user has a Gravatar it will pull it into their profile, if they don't, the picture is left blank.

Here is a browser plug-in that pulls avatars from a URL that isn't Gravatar to modify the Mixpanel UI. In order to use it, you need to store the user's pictures online somewhere else.

Here's the actual link to his javascript plugin: https://gist.github.com/enoex/af39b59b2e6b8255bde2