# Mixpanel People Profile Avatar Image

Tags: ios, mixpanel

I've searched the interwebs for a solution to this, but to no avail.

Is it possible to set our user's profile picture as the profile picture in Mixpanel's people report? I've tried calling our user picture object in the method where we declare Mixpanel user attributes, but it's not updating the photo.

Is there a best practice here?

[image]

Comment: I'm dealing the same situation. My tip for you is to ask mixpanel's support their great, and i'm sure they'll help you. If I'll do it before you, i'll post the solution, cheers.

Answer (score 16):

For the profile image, they use the Gravatar based on the user's email. After countless searching I found [this tweet](https://twitter.com/mixpanel/status/427731730733092864) from Mixpanel.

Answer (score 0):

Avatar `$avatar` - Set this property to a url resource of a gif, jpg, jpeg, or png to update the profile picture in a profile. This property will override a profile picture pulled from Gravatar.

https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004708186-What-is-the-difference-between-Event-Properties-Super-Properties-and-People-Properties-and-which-should-I-use-